# Array element undefined after array.push

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch

I have a directory on my webserver where I upload timestamp.md files for publishing to my "blog"-div on my site. Using javascript to fetch index of dir via scandir() (PHP) returns:

```
["2018-12-05T13:28:10.000Z.md","2018-12-05T12:58:19.858Z.md","2018-12-05T12:37:25.012Z.md","2018-12-05T12:28:52.612Z.md","..","."]
```

I store obve in var "files".

I then do a for-loop with fetch from index.html to get content of all off the timestamp.mds

(I create a emtpy array for storing of md-content)

```
var mdcontent = new Array()

for(var i=0;i<files.length -2;i++) {

    fetch('md/'+files[i])
    .then( response => response.text())
    .then(result => mdcontent.push(result));

}

console.log(mdcontent) returns what looks like a normal array 
consol.log(mdcontent[0]) (or any other element of array) returns undefined.
console.log(mdcontent.lenght) returns 0.
```

The question is how to access elements of this array?

I cant figure out where I went wrong this time and if someone could help me I would appreciate it!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post what `console.log(mdcontent)` returns?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `fetch` it returns `Promise`, which represents an asynchronous operation. You should not access elements of `mdcontent` like you do - it's OK with synchronous code, but not here. Instead you need to wait while every promise (every `fetch` + `.text()`) will be completed. You can do it with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```
var promises = new Array();

for (var i=0; i < files.length - 2; i++) {
    promises.push(
        fetch('md/' + files[i])
        .then(res => res.text())
    );
}

Promise.all(promises).then(mdcontent => {
    console.log(mdcontent);
    console.log(mdcontent.length);
    console.log(mdcontent[0]);
});
```

I suggest you to read about asynchronous javascript. Maybe [this article](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee). It could be hard to use promises, when you don't understand its asynchronous nature. You also may want to use [asynchronous functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and `await` instead of `.then(...)`.

Comment: thanks for the input! You were indeed right. Went the async/wait way to solve my   issue though.   this was my final code: `const request = async () => {  
  const response = await fetch('md/'+files[i])  
  const text = await response.text()  
    var mdcontent = marked(text.toString())  
    console.log(mdcontent)`  }